# How to get package name after lollipop version in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-package-managers

I have tried this below code for getting forground application package name but it is getting my own app application package name only. other application packagte name will be null.it means it is returning null ...how can i get package name.. is there any other way. I know getrunningappprocess is blocked by google.

```
(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    String mpackageName = tasks.get(0).processName;
    UsageStatsManager usage = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(this.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<UsageStats> appList = usage.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
    if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
        SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> runningTask = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
            runningTask.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
        }
        if (!runningTask.isEmpty() && runningTask != null) {
            mpackageName = runningTask.get(runningTask.lastKey()).getPackageName();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; pakageName != null && i < pakageName.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("AppCheck", "comfor2 : " + mpackageName + "    pak2 : " + pakageName.get(i));
        if (mpackageName.equals(pakageName.get(i))) {
            currentApp = pakageName.get(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get class name from below method...

```
public static void classNameRunning(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        // print log for class name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            Log.w("Package name ==> ",componentInfo.getPackageName());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: write also `getPackageName().getClass()` .. might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
public static HashSet<String> getRunningApps(Context context) {
final HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : runningTasks) {
    String packageName = runningTaskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName();
    try {
        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
        hashSet.add(appName);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException exception) {
        // handle Exception
    }
}
return hashSet;
}
```